# Problem with DM and bodyswitching death

Tags: dnd-5e, social-contract

While the party's cleric and I were mid-bodyswap my level 3 warlock got killed by a green gelatinous cube.

The player and I are not on very good terms (he hates me) and my character died because of his poor play.  The Cube insta-killed me and dissolved my corpse (and loot). I am a fairly new player.  I do not know if it is a proper thing for the DM to do. The DM will also only allow us to resurrect our character once, so I get cheated out of a life.

Who is in the right?

Comment: Are you saying that as players you are not on good terms?

Comment: We have frequently had arguments, its never really amounted to much, thanks to our DM, but there is some animosity between us.

Comment: How did you swap bodies?

Comment: Are you saying that the cleric's body and your soul were the target of the cube? Or your body and the cleric's soul? In general resurrection spells require pulling the soul back from beyond, and having some amount of the body already present on the material plane. As for the "fairness" of the act, I don't think that's an answerable question, being pretty much opinion-based.

Comment: The cube killed my (Warlocks) body, when the Cleric was in control of it, I was in control of the Clerics body. The Cleric switched back into his own body when my body died.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based, and as such cannot be answered here. We don't know enough about your table's conventions and social contract to say for sure what is and is not fair and appropriate at your table. The best we can suggest is to talk with your GM about your concerns.

Comment: @keithcurtis Generally speaking, the higher level the resurrection spell is, the less of the body you need, and the longer time you have since it died. True Ress (9th) only requires speaking the creature's name, and it must be dead less than 200 years (and not have died of old age). Oh, and one other minor trifle. A mere 25,000 GP worth of crushed diamonds...

Comment: @Rachel I've made some edits to try to make this a bit more readable--I hope you find they've preserved your original intent. I also removed the [tag:monster] and [tag:new-player] tags as it seems to me the cube and the fact that you're new are really just incidental details, not core to the problem. (How to handle two players--cleric and DM--destroying a third player's--your--game piece.) If you disagree you can always revert the edit by clicking on the "edited [time] ago" link.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "body swap" because that isn't a third level skill or spell that I can find in the books. **The Cleric switched back into his own body when my body died.** What in the blazes does that mean?

Comment: What is the total number of players at the table?at are the levels of the characters in play?

Comment: @tzxAzrael: I realized that. I just didn't want to go into great detail in a comment.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yeah, it's starting to sound like "a player switched pieces with me, broke mine (that he was playing with) and snatched back his piece." A lot of confusing things happening.

Comment: Related question ["Is the DM always right?"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/is-the-dm-always-right)

Answer (score 6):

The DM has very broad authority to tell the story they want to tell.  If the DM sincerely believes that doing a body-switching episode would be fun and interesting for the table, then the DM can do a body-switching episode even if they have to make up all the rules for it from scratch.  (And it sounds like that's what happened here.)  See also: [Is the DM always right?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/is-the-dm-always-right)

Although it's nearly impossible for the DM to be "in the wrong", it's totally possible for the DM to be "not running a fun game".  If the DM isn't running a fun game, it's expected that most or all of their players will leave and find a better DM.  In other words this is a game where you vote with your feet.

If you feel like the game is fun overall, but this *particular* session wasn't fun for you, because the DM gave your character to someone else who then got your character killed -- it would be good to politely let your DM know about that.  If you can draw a clear line, like "I don't really enjoy it when my character gets killed" or "I don't get along with the person playing the cleric, and I don't enjoy it when they have opportunities to get my character killed", that might be helpful.  I sit in the DM seat frequently, and it's often hard to tell when players are having fun, so this sort of feedback is valuable.

Good luck with it.

Comment: Actually, there are body-switching rules - look up *Magic Jar*.

Comment: Agreed that *magic jar* can put one character in another's body, but it doesn't sound like that spell was used in this adventure.

Comment: I don't have a comprehensive list of all D&D modules, but I would speculate that it's very very rare for any published module to use body-switching.  This is both because (1) it's difficult to play someone else's character, especially at high levels, and (2) as OP found out, it's super frustrating when someone else plays your character and gets them killed.

Comment: @AnneAunyme This is 5e ...  occult manuals?

Comment: @Miniman Magic Jar is not a third level skill, nor a spell available to third level players.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think it's pretty safe to assume the DM was responsible for the body-switching, not the players.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: nevermind, it was from pathfinder...

Comment: @miniman We can assume anything we like (and you may be right) but I'd like Rachel to explain what was up. (homebrew? Fine just help us understand the situation a bit better ..)

Comment: Dan, do you think a link to [this related question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/is-the-dm-always-right) would be helpful, or is it too broad/not close enough to this problem?