# Should bards have to pay for their colleges?

Tags: lore, bard

I think that since a college is really just a 'club' or grouping of sorts of bards, it doesn't count as a 'college' in the modern sense of the term. My DM is telling me I have to pay for my College of Lore, which is stupid in my opinion.

Comment: Which edition of which game is this?   (D&D or something else).  [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65543/22566)

Comment: Also, "should" as in "by the rules", or "should" as in "it would be more fair and fitting"?. Really, I'm asking, should the title be "Do Bards pay for their college choices?"?

Comment: Is the DM asking you to pay tuition for your character's education ("college" in the modern sense), or are these more like ongoing membership dues for a fraternal organization ("college" in the sense you're talking about)?

Comment: Without knowing what game you are playing there is no way for us to answer your question. Please note that this site deals with questions from all RPGs and that there are thousands of different ones. Please [edit] your question to include this information. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you being required to pay for the college of Lore before you are allowed to get up another level, or is this a matter of the bard being in debt?